# How to generate numbers between 0-1 in 4200 steps

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to generate floating point numbers between 0 and 1 that are not random. I would like the range to consist of 4200 values so In python I did `1/4200` to get, what number is needed to get from 0-1 in 4200 steps. This gave me the value `0.0002380952380952381`, I confirmed this by doing 0.`0002380952380952381*4200 = 1` (in Python) I have tried:

```
y_axis =  [0.1964457, 0.20904465, 0.22422191, 0.68414455, 0.5341106, 0.49412863]



x1 = [0.18536805, 0.22449078, 0.26378343 ,0.73328144 ,0.63372454, 0.60280087,0.49412863]

y2_axis =  [0.18536805 0.22449078 0.26378343 ... 0.73328144 0.63372454 0.60280087] 0.49412863]

plt.plot(pl.frange(0,1,0.0002380952380952381) , y_axis)
plt.plot(x1,y2)
```

This returns: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4201,) and (4200,)`

I would like help with resolving this, otherwise any other method that would also work would also be appreciated. I am sure other solutions are available and this maybe long winded. Thank you

Comment: Beware of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate the numbers, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[i/4200 for i in range(4201)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy makes this really easy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 4200)
array([  0.00000000e+00,   2.38151941e-04,   4.76303882e-04, ...,
         9.99523696e-01,   9.99761848e-01,   1.00000000e+00])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!